# Cleaned Drive through Diskpart, NO BOOT, NO CMD, NOTHING

Tags: diskpart

I bought a desktop and it wasn't reformatted.

Step 1: Enter Win7 CD. - Would not let me select SSD - Had error message(forgot now) - Googled it and it instructed me to access CMD in Windows start up, `diskpart`, select disk, clean, restart, install.

Step 2: Did instructions, installed it perfectly! Computer running Win7 and working fine

Step 3: My Computer shows both SSD and HDD but the HDD shows as 125GB when it should be 500.

I figured (stupid of me) that I can go into CMD, diskpart, clean that HDD drive to restart it to 500.

Step 4: Restarted it, there is NO display, no CMD, no blinking underscores, nothing. Absolutely nothing.

Things I have done to try to remedy:

- Restart BIOS by removing battery
- Restart with Win7 CD in cddrive
- Restart with Win7 USB in
- Restart with Win7 CD in External CD Drive via USB
- Constantly Pressing F10 / F12 / Del on start up hoping a screen would come up
- Unplugging different combinations of SSD/HDD hoping it would run off one of them
- Unplugging a HDD from another rig, plugging it into the current with no other SSD/HDD

NOTHING. COMES. UP.

Did I brick the RIG?

Comment: What is the make and model of the machine? Please look on the serial number plate for the model #, for a 'marketing' model can be any one of dozens of different configurations. Once you have it, please click on `edit` above and to the left and add that into your original post, so all can see it without weeding through comments.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't sound right...
You can't brick a computer using diskpart. It just isn't possible.
Worst you can do is wipe your drives so you need to re-install.

If you remove SSD and HDD you should be able to get into the Bios setup.
If not something is loose inside. CPU or cooler isn't insatlled properly, RAM has popped out of a socket (or is bad). Cooling fan is disconnected. Something like that.
Or: the motherboard is broken. I hope it is still under warranty in that case.

If you can get it to boot without any disks then insert just the SSD. Do a fresh Windows install on that SSD. Only then re-add the HDD.
This ensures the Windows install AND the boot-files are located on the SSD and the HDD is data-disk only.